# Is having hashtable efficient when there are large number of keys?

Tags: java, hash

I am new to HashMaps. Can anyone tell me Is having hashtable efficient when there are a large number of keys?

Comment: How large you are talking about?

Comment: What alternative are you considering? Efficient compared to?

Comment: Efficient for what? Iterating over? Lookup of keys?

Comment: A hash table is thread-safe, which means synchronization, which means performance cost. If you don't need it to be thread-safe, use a hash map.

Comment: Please clarify your question properly

Comment: Hash table have fast Search and fast Insertion. But size is bigger. Even for a empty hashtable, I think its nearly 300 bytes. Read answers of the below question. There is all you want. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282712/the-fundamentals-of-hash-tables

Answer (score 2):

For HashMap in order to be 'efficient' the map capacity should be larger then the keys number it holds. but more importantly the keys must have `hashCode` method with good hash distribution.

By default java HashMap have load factor 0.75, which means that when you fill it in 75% it will grow its capacity:

from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views
>   requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance
>   (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value
>   mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity
>   too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is
>   important.
>
> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.

But more important is the `hashCode` that you use with your key object.
It should have good (random) distribution equaly hitting all internal indexes (buckets), otherwise with poor `hashCode` your HashMap can behave in worst case even as list with linear search.

With this information you can estimate your performance (basing on available memory & hash key distribution)

Please also check this article:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/10-things-java-developer-should-know-hashmap-chinmay-parekh